Insane middle aged woman obsessed with a mother's baby
The movie involves the crazy middle aged woman and a family (I think miss crazy is their relative of sorts) who has a son and baby. From what I can remember, the movie is about miss crazy obsessed with the mothers baby. Other plot points include:

Miss Crazy hides her insanity, and when the son starts to become suspicious, she subtley taunts the son and sticks her tongue at him
Miss Crazy kills a rather young looking lady helper (who before being lured was tending the family's plants), then proceeds to bury the helpers body in the garden
The father and son moving out due to both seeing Miss Crazy's insanity. The wife still doesn't believe them.
Miss Crazy dies after being flung from the window and her body lies on a bush of roses (her death happens at night)

I think it was from the 1990's, not likely made in the 2000's. In English and from the US. I saw it on TV. If any of you are familiar with any of the plot and know the movie, please tell. Thank you =)

Approximate year of release? Country\language? Where\when did you see it? I think I know what you're after, but these would really help.

I think 1990's, but the movie was not likely made in the 2000's. Language and country of origins, English and US respectively. I saw it on TV.

Sounds like you're after Hush Little Baby from 1994 with Diane Ladd.

Edie's baby girl, Susan, was taken from her arms when she was put into a mental hospital for attempted murder on her baby daughter! Thirty five years down the track Edie is released and tracks her daughter down. She enters her daughter's household and destroys her relationship with her adoptive parents. She is eventually found to be evil, in Susan's eyes and must face a harsh reality...

I'm pretty sure everything you mentioned is there (she's obsessed with her biological daughter's baby, alienates the father and son and drives them away, kills their nanny and buries her in the garden and eventually falls out the window to her death). Here's the trailer:




Thank you very much, this is the movie I have been looking for =)
